# Am I a 'disregarded entity'?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business

The US IRS classifies certain business entities as "disregarded" for tax purposes: business income is considered personal to the owner. The IRS says this term applies only to single-owner LLCs (not partnerships, S-corps etc).

However, I've had a sole prop/DBA for many years that has its own identity, mailing address and EIN. I report on schedule C using this separate EIN. All invoicing, banking, advertising etc is done under the entity name. This is a close parallel to a single-owner LLC, but it isn't one -- it's been around longer than those.

I'm trying to set up a Kindle self-publishing arrangement with Amazon but in the 'tax interview' they seem to think this arrangement can't exist -- at least they don't have a slot for it. If I'm a DBA, they want to use my SSN, saying that sole props don't have separate EINs. And yet... I do, and I want to use it and the entity name and bank account.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is my DBA really a 'disregarded entity' even though it doesn't fit the IRS criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the income is reported on your personal return via Schedule C, your business is a disregarded entity. Having an EIN doesn't change that status, it just allows you to not use your SSN for everything.

Amazon may be unnecessarily rigid, but according to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/do-you-need-an-ein) you don't need an EIN if you don't:

- Have employees.
- Operate your business as a corporation or a partnership.
- File any of these tax returns: Employment, Excise, or Alcohol, Tobacco and Firearms
- Withhold taxes on income, other than wages, paid to a non-resident alien.
- Have a Keogh plan.
- Involved with any of the following types of organizations:

  - Trusts, except certain grantor-owned revocable trusts, IRAs, Exempt Organization Business Income Tax Returns
  - Estates
  - Real estate mortgage investment conduits
  - Non-profit organizations
  - Farmers' cooperatives
  - Plan administrators

So Amazon is probably just using your lack of need for an EIN as a rule that you shouldn't have one, might contact their support since you want to use the EIN.

Comment: Thanks. I did at one time need an EIN, but that part of the business went away some years ago. It never occurred to me to abandon it, but I can see how it's become unnecessary. I don't like being disregarded, though (-:

Comment: @JimMack If only they'd disregard the income too, ay?

Comment: I don't think it would be worth the effort to try to convince someone at Amazon to take your EIN instead of your SS#.  Sounds like a huge headache.  You'd be better off just giving them your SS#.